# I cannot source script to rmarkdown chunk

Tags: r-markdown

I using rmarkdown for the first time and I am trying to run the chunk code with the code written on it or sourcing from script but it does not work either way. I get the following message when I knit:

> Quitting from lines 23-24 (Southside.Rmd)
>   Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'final' not found
>   Calls:  ... source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> %>% -> eval -> eval
>   Execution halted

What surprises me is that if I run the code from the script it works!!

Here is the code:

```
final %>%
  filter(!is.na (violationstotal), !is.na (Agebuilding), !is.na (INdexrehabless6), !is.na (totalvalue)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Agebuilding, y=violationstotal, color=INdexrehabless6,
                     size=totalvalue), alpha=1/2)+ # 1/2 means 50% transparency of color
  annotate("text", label="Older, less expensive and in need of more rehabilitation", x=90, y=10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(final$violationstotal, na.rm = TRUE))+
  annotate("text", label="Mean Violations Total", x=70, y=mean(final$violationstotal, na.rm = TRUE)+1)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=mean(final$Agebuilding, na.rm = TRUE))+
  annotate("text", label="Mean Age Building", y=30, x=mean(final$Agebuilding, na.rm = TRUE)-20 )+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), legend.key = element_blank())+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Quality of Housing")+
  scale_size_continuous(name="Total Value Property")+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Age of properties")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Total of Violations")
```

Comment: This error is mostly connected to the fact that `final` is part of your environment so it works if you run the chunk. If you knit the file, the obejct is not known. So you have to load it in your markdown-file.

Comment: It is my first time using R Markdown, how do I load my file into my markdown file?

Comment: How is the object `final` be created? Can you show us your code?

Comment: I will add the code to my questions. It is a csv file converted to tibble

Comment: So you have to include the loading of the CSV file into your rmarkdown script!

Comment: I did that and it worked, but my html presentation it shows all the results (including the loading of the file) with two # # (my code chunk is run within ``` and with option output only, any idea what's happening now?

Comment: add `include=FALSE`to your code chunk header

Comment: If I do that it hides both the code and the plot in the presentation

Comment: Separate loading and plotting

Comment: That worked!! (I started to guessing it but you told me first). It is an easy fix (loading the tibble in r markdown again and separating loading from the coding for the output. I was checking some aids to learn how to use r markdown but I did not see any advise regarding this simple steps. Thank you so much @J_F

Comment: I have a follow up question to this. Rmakrdown worked with the adjustments, but if now I tried to source the same functions from a script (instead of putting all the code in the code chunk using : source("script.R") when I knit it the presentation appears but empty. It does not show the plot (if I click show output and code it shows only the code itself: source("script.R") . Any ideas?